# Fire single query on user click

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I was attempting to use Apollo's `useLazyQuery` to perform a query in a drawer component when and only when a user clicks a button, but it doesn't seem to be working. Every time I click to close the component, or open the component again, the query is again fired.

It looks like maybe `useLazyQuery` fires when variables are provided to it, so I've tried setting a local state const with `useState` and then setting the value back to null or undefined once the query finishes, but that doesn't seem to work either.

I've tried several combinations of `useEffect`, `useState`, and `useLazyQuery` with and without a `testHandler` callback function and see the same behavior.

I've also tried setting the `fetchPolicy` on the query both to `network-only` and `no-cache` without luck. And I've tried using `onCompleted` in `useLazyQuery` like this:

```
const [getData, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_DATA, {
    onCompleted: () => {
      // Do something
    },
    onError: e => {
      // Do something else
    },
    context: { clientName: 'search' },
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
  });
```

Has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The default fetch policy for Apollo is **cache-first**. If you do not set a fetch policy yourself, this is what will be used.
If you don’t expect your data to change, or if you are taking care to explicitly update the cache when changes are made, this is a good option.

so try with remove **fetchPolicy**